# Async Calls in React with Back4app

Tags: reactjs, back4app

Hi ppl i am using Back4app as Backend i have it on a file like this.
Im using a class to encapsulate Parse.

```
      import Parse from 'parse';

  Parse.serverURL = process.env.REACT_APP_URL;
  Parse.initialize(
    process.env.REACT_APP_appID,
    process.env.REACT_APP_JSkey
  );

  class ParseApp {
    constructor() {
      this.app = Parse;
      this.userClass = Parse.Object.extend('CustomUsers');

    }

    addUser = (name, email) => {
      const userDB = new this.userClass();
      userDB.set('UserName', name);
      userDB.set('email', email);
      userDB.save().then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }

    getUsers = () => {
      let Users = []
      const queryUsers = new Parse.Query(this.userClass);
      queryUsers.find().then((results) => {
          Users = results.map((user) => {
            return {
              id: user.id,
              userName: user.attributes.UserName,
              email: user.attributes.email
            };
          });
          return Users;

      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }

  export default new ParseApp();
```

and i use it this way:

```
          import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
      import Note from './note';
      import './notes.css'
      import UserNameMailForm from './userNameMailForm';
      import shortid from 'shortid';
      import ParseApp from '../parse';

      const NoteApp = (props) => {
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);



      useEffect(() => {
        const Users = ParseApp.getUsers();

      }, []);

      const handleClick = () => {
        console.log(users);
      }

      const addNewUser = (userName, email) => {
        ParseApp.addUser(userName, email);

      }
      return (
          <div className="container p-0">
          <div
            className="screen pt-1 pb-1"
            style={{overflowY: 'scroll'}}
          >
              {/* {users.map((user) => {
                  return <Note key={shortid.generate()} userName={user.userName} email={user.email} />
              })} */}
          </div>
              <UserNameMailForm addUser={addNewUser} />
              <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Show</button>
          </div>
      );
      }

      export default NoteApp;
```

I get correct results on the parse class method i created, but undefined on the react component, what im doing wrong? What approach should i follow.
If you could give me some advice on which approach should i follow.

Comment: what do you mean 'undefined'? Your React Component doesn't render anything? You get an error message during compilation/runtime? Please elaborate.

Comment: i got the correct query result when i console.log on my parse method, but i got undefined when i try to obtain the result on my component using the method.

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by correct results  (or how you get them). How are you getting the results with the Parse Class and how are you using the React Class?

Comment: Ok ill try again, sorry im quite beginner. On the first file I created a Class to encapsulate Parse and define a few methods, getUsers create a query and retrieve an array with the results, if console.log that result i get the correct response, but when I import an instance of my Class on the react component (in useEffect) and try to use getUser there i cant get the same result,  something related to asynchrony?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need something like this:

```
getUsers = () => {
      let Users = []
      const queryUsers = new Parse.Query(this.userClass);
      return queryUsers.find().then((results) => {      // note 'return' added!!!
          Users = results.map((user) => {
            return {
              id: user.id,
              userName: user.attributes.UserName,
              email: user.attributes.email
            };
          });
          return Users;

      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

And then in your React Component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ParseApp.getUsers().then(users => setUsers(users));
});
```

Are you sure you can import the Parse file like that though? It looks suspiciously like a backend file (which you can't run on the frontend). Not sure if Back4app enables you to do that, however.

Comment: Thnks for your time. The other method addUser works fine, it works, but with this method im just sending data not retrieving it. I take the import info from here https://mobile.back4app.com/docs/platform/get-started/parse-sdk

Comment: I tried your approach cose it worked well trying the same with firebase but it gave me some kind of error, cant remember cose im not on my pc, sorry